# React Native: Can you force react-native run-ios to use a different installation of XCode?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

I have a React Native app, and when I run `react-native run-ios`, it opens fine in the default emulator. This is with `XCode 11.1`. I want to use an `iPhone 12 pro max` emulator, which comes with `XCode 12.1`. The `XCode 11.1` came from the app store, and I was able to get `XCode 12.1` only from the apple developer site, so `XCode 11.1` and `XCode 12.1` are both installed separately on my system.

When I try to `Run` the app from `XCode 12.1`, the build fails, so at the moment the only way I can run the app is with `react-native run-ios`, but this uses simulators from `XCode 11.1` and therefore doesn't allow me to use the `iPhone 12 pro max`.

**What I Want To Know:** Is there a way I can force `react-native run-ios` to use `XCode 12.1` instead of `XCode 11.1`? I want to keep both `XCode 11.1` and `XCode 12.1` on my system, and run the app using `react-native run-ios`.

Comment: If you run `react-native run-ios --help` it lists some configuration things you can do. Maybe one of those options will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Set in your Xcode preference (command line tool selection)

Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Choose Command Line Tools -> Choose version -> Close Xcode

then

react-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

You could set the desired Xcode using this in the terminal:

sudo xcode-select -s <path/to/>Xcode.app